# ':runClient'. > Process 'command 'C:\Users\NB\.jdks\semeru-1.8.0_382\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I Was writing a mod for minecraft 1.12.2, the build was successful(im using intellij idea community edition 2021.3). i used the command that runs minecraft or runClient and IT gave me a ERROR:
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\NB.jdks\semeru-1.8.0_382\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you show the full console log? Show your code and give more details?

Comment: Like what? @Elikill58?. the console log was only:

    Process 'command 'C:\Users\NB.jdks\semeru-1.8.0_382\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

    Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Check the log file of your client, you should have more detail somewhere